# Windows 2008 task scheduler tasks can have user interface?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

on Windows 2003 server, scheduled tasks appeared on the console if the user was logged in at the time the task started. eg a scheduled task run as user xyz would appear on the screen if xyz user was logged in. This was the default behaviour on 2003 but isnt on 2008. Is there some way to get it to work on 2008?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the result of [session 0 isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx).  Essentially your scheduled task was exploiting a security hole in Windows that was closed in Windows Vista (and your scheduled task itself might have represented a security hole).

You can configure your task to run as the interactively logged on user which should probably resolve your issue.